# GET request and Fancybox working with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I'm pretty sure theoretically what I am trying to do should work and I believe my syntax is correct. But it would be good to get some fresh eyes on it.

I want to pull in articles from a site (GET request) and display those articles in a fancybox, so my users wouldn't need to leave the site. What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help on this.

```
<ul class="box_qa">
        <% @hero_news.each do |item| %>
            <li>
            <%= item["webTitle"] %> <%= link_to "Read more!", item["webUrl"], :class=>"fancybox" %>
            <span class="timestamp">
             Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(item["webPublicationDate"])%> ago.
            </span>
            </li>
        <% end %>
</ul>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a.fancybox").fancybox({'type': 'image'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: The error: The fancybox seems to work, but I get an error "
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."

Comment: if you changed the type to `iframe` then you need to set `width` and `height` (and eventually `autoScale` for v1.3.4 or `fitToView` for v2.x to `false`)

Answer (score 0):

Switched "image" to iframe. Stil having sizing issues however.

Comment: better try editing you own question for updates rather than answering yourself with something that didn't solve the issue.